# Do a $http.get( ) based off of a selection from another $http.get( )

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am working a proof of concept on plunker right now. I am trying to fill a dropdown with data that I am pulling from an `$http.get( )` and based on user selection I want to make another `$http.get( )` call to another rest api and get data that relates and use it in an `ng-repeat` list. Currently I have the first part working, but I do not know how to make the second call. I am using [this](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) fake rest api for the first set of data, and populating the dropdown with the `id`'s, which there are 100. Secondly, I want to let the user select 1-100 from the dropdown and display the matching set of emails from [this](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments) fake rest api based on their `postId` which there are 500.

I hope that makes enough sense. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zebYk299nf9zRElwZqSO?p=preview) is the plunker that I have 1/2 way working.

**EDIT TO CLARIFY:**

The options in the `<select>` are supposed to be all `id`'s from [here](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts). There are 100 unique `id`'s.

The `<li>`'s of the `<ul>` are supposed to be the corresponding `email`'s that have the same `postId` as the `<select>` above - found [here](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments).

So if I choose `1` from the dropdown, I want the emails from these to make up the list:

```
{
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "id labore ex et quam laborum",
    "email": "Eliseo@gardner.biz",
    "body": "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos\ntempora quo necessitatibus\ndolor quam autem quasi\nreiciendis et nam sapiente accusantium"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "quo vero reiciendis velit similique earum",
    "email": "Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com",
    "body": "est natus enim nihil est dolore omnis voluptatem numquam\net omnis occaecati quod ullam at\nvoluptatem error expedita pariatur\nnihil sint nostrum voluptatem reiciendis et"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "name": "odio adipisci rerum aut animi",
    "email": "Nikita@garfield.biz",
    "body": "quia molestiae reprehenderit quasi aspernatur\naut expedita occaecati aliquam eveniet laudantium\nomnis quibusdam delectus saepe quia accusamus maiores nam est\ncum et ducimus et vero voluptates excepturi deleniti ratione"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "name": "alias odio sit",
    "email": "Lew@alysha.tv",
    "body": "non et atque\noccaecati deserunt quas accusantium unde odit nobis qui voluptatem\nquia voluptas consequuntur itaque dolor\net qui rerum deleniti ut occaecati"
  },
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "id": 5,
    "name": "vero eaque aliquid doloribus et culpa",
    "email": "Hayden@althea.biz",
    "body": "harum non quasi et ratione\ntempore iure ex voluptates in ratione\nharum architecto fugit inventore cupiditate\nvoluptates magni quo et"
  },
  {
```

So I want my list to look like this when `1` is selected:

- Eliseo@gardner.biz
- Jayne_Kuhic@sydney.com
- Nikita@garfield.biz
- Lew@alysha.tv
- Hayden@althea.biz

Hope that helps clear it up.

Comment: It looks like you have it right. Just `search()` is undefined in the `onChange()` function. Right there you can call the `$http.get()` and populate the data field by applying the info to `$scope.records`

Comment: Sorry, I am not 100% sure what you are trying to say. Could you maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I didn't understand it fully. Right now, it gets all of the posts, and stuffs them in the `ul` *and* in the `select` dropdown. Then when you select one of them, it calls the undefined `search()` function. What do you actually want it to do?

Comment: Crossed wires. Heh. Just focus on my second comment. What is the behaviour you want from the `ul`, `select` and `input`?

Comment: i think the search is just from testing stuff out a bit ago. On the html where I have the `{{item.email}}` thats just bogus for now. I want that to be all of the emails from the second fake rest api that have the same `postId` as what is chosen in the dropdown.

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand what the flow should be. What should be in the `ul`, in the `select`? What should happen when a user clicks `select`?

Comment: OK, I get it. Updating for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bunch of things going on here:

- You want to separate your on-change function for filtering from selecting
- You want to leverage the ng-model for the select in the callback
- You want to load the records of the `ul` only after selecting
- Ideally, the filtering by `postId` should be server-side, so you only get the data you need; of course, with no server, just a simple file `GET`, not much you can do about that, but I would add it at the `$http.get()` rather than the html, since that is where you do the get (actually, I would extract it to a service, but that is a different issue entirely)

I updated the plunkr for you to get the select working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/4VEFBCIybk4mEO0mxGa2?p=preview

Actually, you don't even need the `filter()` callback, since you use it correctly in the `ng-repeat` of the `ul`, so I eliminated it. Use the updated plunkr instead

Comment: Holy moly. You are a legend.  I did still want to use the search, filter, and on change though, but what you gave me is a tremendous start. Kudos good sir.

Comment: You are going to make me blush! Nah, just struggled through the same issues and paying it forward. Use it well.